# How to assign a List of Booleans to a generated Checkbox IsChecked property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I've recently started learning C# and I've encountered a problem. I display a set of keywords in a generated checkbox in my WPF and I want to check the element (IsChecked) based on an input check from a TXT file.
If the currently selected element from a different listbox matches the read modelclass(from a txt file) then set the checked key true.

I'm generating a Checkbox in my WPF to list a set of keywords that my app reads from a txt file.
The txt file contains the following items per line:
-id
-key
-pair
-description

WPF code:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XAMLModelKeywords}" SelectedItem="{Binding XAMLModelKeyword}" Margin="5" x:Name="listofallkeys" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding XAMLAssignedKeys}" Content="{Binding Key}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

C#:

```
        public ModelTemplates XAMLModelTemplate { get; set; }

        public ModelKeywords XAMLModelKeyword { get; set; }
        public List<bool> XAMLAssignedKeys { get; set; }


        public string XAMLKeyword { get; set; }

        public ViewModelMain()
        {
            //This creates a new instance of ObservableCollection above
            XAMLModelTemplates = new ObservableCollection<ModelTemplates>();
            XAMLModelKeywords = new ObservableCollection<ModelKeywords>();
            XAMLAssignedKeys = new List<bool>();
            Refresh();
        }

     public void Refresh()
        {
            XAMLModelTemplates.Clear();
            foreach (ModelTemplates tpl in ReadInput.ReadTemplateDirectory(Path))
            {
                XAMLModelTemplates.Add(tpl);
            }
            //Selecting the first item from the returned list
            XAMLModelTemplate = XAMLModelTemplates.FirstOrDefault();
    
            XAMLModelKeywords.Clear();
            foreach (ModelKeywords tpl in ReadInput.ReadKeywordsFile(KeyWordsPath))
            {
                XAMLModelKeywords.Add(tpl);
            }
            XAMLModelKeyword = XAMLModelKeywords.FirstOrDefault();
    
            XAMLAssignedKeys.Clear();
            foreach (ModelKeywords tpl in XAMLModelKeywords)
            {
    
                XAMLAssignedKeys.Add(ReadInput.CheckPairedtemplates(tpl, XAMLModelTemplate));
            }
```

ModelKeyword:

```
    public class ModelKeywords
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public List<string> PairedTemplates { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

ModelTemplate:

```
    public class ModelTemplates
    {
        //path to a template
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TemplatePath { get; set; }
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public ExcelRange TemplateRange { get; set; }
    }
```

ReadKeywordsFile:
Returns a list of Template Models (name of template file, path) and the displays it in a listbox.

ReadKeywordsFile:
Returns a list of Keywords Model (id, key, pair, desc) and then displays it in a generated listbox.

CheckPairedtemplates:
Returns a list of booleans based on  the currently selected Template Model matches the Keywords Model pair (list of string).

TLDR:
I have a list of booleans ( XAMLAssignedKeys) and I want to match it to my generated checkbox in WPF, however the generation happens based on an item template and I'm not sure how to link one element from my list of booleans to the checkbox "IsChecked" property.

[ScreenshotofApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obh82.png)

Thank you much in advance for the advices.

Comment: Your codes are incomplete. What is the content of ModelKeywords?

Comment: Hello! It's a simple ModelClass. Here are the contents:
    
`
public class ModelKeywords
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public List<string> PairedTemplates { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
`

Comment: I would recommend to refine your question itself adding that class. In addition, your classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged? It is the basic of WPF MVVM pattern.

Comment: Added models to my question. I'll look into this INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set ObservableCollection<ModelKeywords> (XAMLModelKeywords) to `ItemsSource` property of ListView (listofallkeys), each item of the ListView will be bound to a member of the ObservableCollection. In this case, the CheckBox inside DataTemplate will be bound to a ModelKeywords in XAMLModelKeywords. Therefore, you need to bind the properties of CheckBox with the properties of ModelKeywords.

In the Xaml, you mistakenly set XAMLAssignedKeys to `IsChecked` property of CheckBox. It must be a property of ModelKeywords. The remedy will be to add a bool property to ModelKeywords, somehow copy a value in the XAMLAssignedKeys to the property, and then bind the property with `IsChecked` properties of CheckBox.

Let's say, if you add `IsEnabled` bool property to ModelKeywords, the Xaml will be

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}" Content="{Binding Key}"/>
```

In addition, unless you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to ModelKeywords, only initial value of the property will be sent to the CheckBox and the subsequent values will not be notified and reflected to the CheckBox when the property is changed.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! https://9gag.com/gag/aZ0mve0